# move files with spaces in file name using batch script

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have next code and it works perfectly as far as there are no spaces in file names.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%n IN (`dir D:\Skripte\radno\temp /b`) DO @FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,3,4 delims=. " %%d IN (`date /t`) DO @move D:\App\STE\_Isporuka\Doc\%%n \\gds21-bdc01\STE\Arhiva\Novo\Doc\%%f%%e%%d-%%n
```

I need same functionality for files with spaces in file names.

Thanks,
Tiho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set a blank delimiter to the first for loop and quote the filenames in the second loop:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=" %%n IN (`dir D:\Skripte\radno\temp /b`) DO @FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,3,4 delims=. " %%d IN (`date /t`) DO @move "D:\App\STE\_Isporuka\Doc\%%n" "\\gds21-bdc01\STE\Arhiva\Novo\Doc\%%f%%e%%d-%%n"
```