# Batch file Loop with spaces

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, directory

I have this tiny annoying thing that is driving me nuts.
I need to loop through a directory and move files contained within a subdir to another location.

This works fine for folders that don't contain any spaces, but I have some directories that contain spaces, which do not work.
I've tried adding some "" around the file location, but that doesn't work either.

This is what I have:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b D:\adir\dir with spaces`) do (
    MOVE /Y "D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%m\*.*" "D:\bdir\dir with spaces"
    RD /q D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%m
)
```

Comment: Refer to answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633694/move-files-with-spaces-in-file-name-using-batch-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is put quotes inside the parentheses and in the RD command:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b "D:\adir\dir with spaces"`) do (
    MOVE /Y "D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%m\*.*" "D:\bdir\dir with spaces"
    RD /q "D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%m"
```

Then I would see how it goes...

This (with quotes) "works for me":

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b "z:\dir with spaces"`) do (
    dir "z:\dir with spaces\%%m"
)
```

This (without the quotes) does NOT work:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b z:\dir with spaces`) do (
    dir z:\dir with spaces\%%m
)
```

Comment: Tried that, but it does not take the files - the result shows: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: OMFG! You wouldn't believe what happened - I had the bloody directory name wrong. Sorry to have wasted your time. But the "quotes" do work.

Comment: @Rik: Don't be ashamed, it happens all the time, to all of us. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%m in ('dir /b /ad "D:\adir\dir with spaces"') do (
    MOVE "D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%~m\*" "D:\bdir\dir with spaces"
    RD "D:\adir\dir with spaces\%%~m"
```